# How do I get Android kitkat 4.4?

Tags: nexus-7, 4.4-kitkat

I have Android 4.3 jelly bean on my Nexus 7. How do I get Kitkat?

I have tried exploring the Android website. I have also found some tutorials out there like this one - http://www.ibtimes.com/android-44-kitkat-update-how-manually-update-nexus-7-latest-android-firmware-tutorial-1469800

but they seem to require taking steps that are quite low-level. I don't think a consumer like me is supposed to delve into such a low-level ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really just if you want to do the upgrade manually, *now*. Google's own devices (the Nexus range) have always received the latest OS versions sooner or later over the air (called "OTA").

Actually, they've started seeding it now, [according to Team Android](http://www.teamandroid.com/2013/11/13/update-nexus-7-2013-android-44-krt16o-kitkat-ota-official-software-update/) on an article published November 15th:

> The new WiFi version Nexus 7 2013 can now be updated to Android 4.4 KRT16O KitKat OTA software update. The official Android 4.4 KitKat has just begun rolling out to users starting today and Google will be pushing out this firmware update to everyone in the coming days.